# PHP AJAX Load More

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi i have a script that when user click load more button, ajax will request new content and 
display to users, but i have issue where if all the content has been loaded and if user click load more button it cause bug and repeatedly show multiple load more button.Following is my code, need to know how to resolve this. If there is no content to load the button need to be disabled.Thanks guys !!

ajax_more.php

```
 <?php
include("config.php");


if(isSet($_POST['lastmsg']))
{
$lastmsg=$_POST['lastmsg'];
$result=mysql_query("select * from messages where mes_id<'$lastmsg' limit 3");
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$msg_id=$row['mes_id'];
$message=$row['msg'];
?>


<li>
<?php echo $message; ?>
</li>


<?php
}


?>

<div id="more<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="morebox">
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="more">more</a>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

loadmore.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Twitter Style load more results.</title>
<link href="frame.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
//More Button
$('.more').live("click",function() 
{
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
if(ID)
{
$("#more"+ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_more.php",
data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("ol#updates").append(html);
$("#more"+ID).remove();
}
});
}
else
{
$(".morebox").html('The End');

}


return false;


});
});

</script>
<style>
body
{
font-family:Arial, 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
color:#000;
font-size:15px;

}
a { text-decoration:none; color:#0066CC}
a:hover { text-decoration:underline; color:#0066cc }
*
{ margin:0px; padding:0px }
ol.timeline
    { list-style:none}ol.timeline li{ position:relative;border-bottom:1px #dedede dashed; padding:8px; }ol.timeline li:first-child{}
    .morebox
    {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333333;
    text-align:center;
    border:solid 1px #333333;
    padding:8px;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .morebox a{ color:#333333; text-decoration:none}
    .morebox a:hover{ color:#333333; text-decoration:none}
    #container{margin-left:60px; width:580px }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="padding:4px; margin-bottom:10px; border-bottom:solid 1px #333333; "><h3>Tutorial Link <a href="http://9lessons.blogspot.com/2009/12/twitter-style-load-more-results-with.html">Click Here</a></h3></div>
<div id='container'>
<ol class="timeline" id="updates">
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from messages  LIMIT 3");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$msg_id=$row['mes_id'];
$message=$row['msg'];
?>
<li>
<?php echo $message; ?>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ol>
<div id="more<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="morebox">
<a href="#" class="more" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>">more</a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont get what you want, and whats wrong?? Whats your aim... like should the button disappear once loaded??? or what??

Comment: hi thanks for you feedback, i solved this problem already. Actually not i want the button to disappear or what so ever. There is bug with the code. Once all content loaded and if user click the button again the button itself repeated many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$count=0;
$done=false;
if(isSet($_POST['lastmsg']))
{
$lastmsg=$_POST['lastmsg'];
$result=mysql_query("select * from messages where mes_id<'$lastmsg' limit 3");
$check=mysql_result(mysql_query("select mes_id from messages ORDER BY mes_id ASC limit 1"));
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$msg_id=$row['mes_id'];
$message=$row['msg'];
if($row['mes_id']==$check){$done=true;}
$count++;
?>


<li>
<?php echo $message; ?>
</li>


<?php
}

if($count>0 && !$done){
?>

<div id="more<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="morebox">
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="more">more</a>
</div>

<?php
}
}
?>
```

Explanation: You were unconditionally outputting the more link. With the changes made, the script checks if more than 0 messages have been loaded from the table before outputting a more link. I have also updated it to check if the current batch is the last and not output the more div if it is.

Answer (score 1):

try this code;

```
   $.ajax({
**$("#load_buton").attr("disabled","disabled");**
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_more.php",
    data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $("ol#updates").append(html);
    $("#more"+ID).remove();
**$("#load_buton").removeAttr("disabled");**
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the php section, only display the More button if your returned row size count is greater than 0

Edge cases:

1. If your database table size increases by n rows, you will repeat n
   records each time you hit More
2. As above, but if records are removed, you will miss out records

Security issues:

1. SQL injection by sending "0'; truncate messages;--" in the last message post field
2. Cross site scripting - if users can submit messages with HTML/JavaScript they will be returned in the content without escaping.

In both cases above, use. MySQL escape string ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php ), or use mysqli, and use htmlentities ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php )